# Laptop is using Intel HD 4000 instead of GeForce 630M

Tags: windows, laptop, windows-8.1, graphics-card, nvidia-graphics-card

I have a dedicated GFX card in my laptop, but DxDiag and GPU-Z say it's using the Intel HD graphics.

I disabled the Intel HD 4000 driver in Device Manager, but it didn't work. I searched for a setting in the BIOS, but there was none. The Nvidia driver is 100% up to date. The laptop is in high performance mode and plugged in. The OS is Windows 8.1

Comment: It being "100% update" is the entire problem.  You should be using the OEM display drivers

Comment: @Ramhound I don't agree at all. By that logic, nobody with a laptop can ever update their graphic drivers.

Comment: I am curious about the model of the laptop. I have a similar setup and Optimus needs to be enabled for the NVidia drivers to work properly... but, ugh, those NVidia drivers are a PITA sometimes.

Comment: It is a Dell 15Z 5523

Comment: @MichaelFrank - Sure they can provided they updated to a driver that supports switchable graphics, which requires using the modded versions of the current drivers for both AMD and Nvidia, which isn't waht the author is doing.  Besides using the OEM Driver only gets it working

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem with a GT650M last year.  I just disabled the Nvidia GPU in Device Manager then re-enabled it and that worked OK for me.